# Angular Custom Directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to Angular and I've been reading their docs in angular.io and I did not see anything connected to creating my own directives with template.

I'm wondering if this directive below can be done in angular 2?

javascript file

```
app.directive('sideDishRowDisplay', function($compile) {
      return {
        scope: {
            sideDishRowDisplay: "=", //import referenced model to our directives scope
            sideDishList: "="
        },
        templateUrl: 'html/templates/sideDishRow.html',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {       
        }
      }
    })
```

sideDishRow.html

```
<select class="inputField" ng-model="sideDishRowDisplay.sideDishSelect" ng-change="$parent.$parent.getTotalPrice()"
        ng-options="dish.name for dish in sideDishList | filter: dish.type='sideDish'" required>
        <option value="">-- Select Side Dish --</option>
    </select>
</td>
<td>
    <!-- Binding the input field to the parent to the cost of the item. -->
    <input class=inputPrice type="number" ng-model="sideDishRowDisplay.sideDishSelect.price" disabled required>
</td>
 <td>
    <button ng-if="sideDishRowDisplay.name != 'sideDishRow0'" ng-click="$parent.$parent.removeSideDishRow(sideDishRowDisplay)">Remove</button>
 </td>
```

main.html

```
</tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="field in data.fields" side-dish-row-display="field" side-dish-list="dishList">   
</tr>
```

Comment: Well, yes, it can be done, but do you want people to write the actual code for you, or you just need some directions? If option two, please provide some insight into what you have already tried and where did you struggle

Comment: Can you provide me the actual code? if you don't mind, I've wasted a lot of time in this and I can learn faster by tracing actual codes than reading documentations which I know it is not a good habit but I get confused on understanding terminologies on different technologies. I'm getting better on understanding docs though.

Comment: @remy_zero There are plenty of services around which allow you to pay people to write code for you. SO is not such a service.